# How to get data from Dialogfragment to fragment with interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I'm trying to get data from dialogfragment into fragment by passing them with interface.So far i know that first because its fragment i need to implement the interface on the MainActivity and from there send the data to any fragment that i want.
I understand that but i dont know how to do that.
So far i have implemented in the MainActivity the interface, I'm getting the data but i dont know how to send it to the fragment.

**Main Activity**

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements ChangeProfileImgDialog.OnPhotoReceivedListener{
    //these the methods that i implement
       @Override
public void getImagePath(Uri imagePath) {
    Log.d("imagepath",imagePath.toString());
}

@Override
public void getImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Log.d("imagepath",bitmap.toString());
}
```

**Dialog Fragment** - this dialogfragment gets a picture from gallery/camera

```
  public class ChangeProfileImgDialog extends DialogFragment {

      public interface OnPhotoReceivedListener{
    public void getImagePath(Uri imagePath);
    public void getImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap);


}

OnPhotoReceivedListener mOnPhotoReceived;

     @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    /*
    Results when selecting new image from phone memory
     */
    if(requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: image: " + selectedImageUri);
            //send the uri and fragment to the interface
            mOnPhotoReceived.getImagePath(selectedImageUri);
            getDialog().dismiss();
    }

    else if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: done taking a photo.");

        Bitmap bitmap;
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        //send the bitmap and fragment to the interface
        mOnPhotoReceived.getImageBitmap(bitmap);
        getDialog().dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    try{
        mOnPhotoReceived = (OnPhotoReceivedListener)this.getActivity();
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage(), e.getCause() );
    }
    super.onAttach(context);
}
```

**Fragment** - this fragment should get the data from the dialogfragment. but it should come from the MainActivity.

```
    public class MyAccountFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,
                                       ChangeProfileImgDialog.OnPhotoReceivedListener{

  @Override
public void getImagePath(Uri imagePath) {
    if( !imagePath.toString().equals("")){
        mSelectedImageUri = imagePath;
        mSelectedImageBitmap = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "getImagePath: got the image uri: " + mSelectedImageUri);
    }
}

@Override
public void getImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(bitmap != null){
        mSelectedImageUri = null;
        mSelectedImageBitmap = bitmap;
        Log.d(TAG, "getImageBitmap: got the image bitmap: " + mSelectedImageBitmap);
    }
}
```

I hope you understood me, What im trying to do is just to get the data from dialogfragment to the fragment. 
Becuase its fragment and im using interface i need to implement this interface in the MainActivity and then some how move the data to the fragment.
Any idea how do i move the data into the fragment?

Comment: from what I have understood is, you have an activity and in that activity you have a dialogfragment and myaccountfragment. So whenever the user chooses a pic the dialogfragment is called and from that onActivityResult is called. And you now want to pass this data to myaccountfragment. right?

Comment: The dialogFragment called from "MyAccountFragment". The data that i get from the dialogFragment pass by interface to "MainActivity". what im trying to do is to pass that data to "MyAccountFragment"

Comment: where do you call MyAccountFragment?

Comment: from the "MainActivity" - i use "onNavigationItemSelected"

Comment: Then you have to send it using Bundle

Answer (score 1):

You can add check for the fragment. 
Whenever you get the callback in the overrided methods in your MainActivity
use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(pass the id of the container)` or can use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(pass your fragment tag name)` like this:-

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(//pass the id of the container)
if(fragment instanceOf MyAccountFragment){
//after this 
fragment.sendDataToFragment(//Your data);
}
```

Comment: How do i get the data when i pass it to "MyAccountFragment"?

Comment: you will send the data in the fragment.sendDataToFragment(//Your data); method as an argument and can use that in the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a Interface

```
public interface CallBackInterface{
    public void OnCustomerDetailsCallback(String getDetailsData);
}
```

Then implement this interface in Your MyAccountFragment

Call DialogFragment like this from MyAccountFragment

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        dialogFragment dFragment = new dialogFragment ();
        if (dFragment != null) {
            dFragment.onAttachToParentFragment(this);
        }
        dFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        dFragment.show(fm, "Dialog Fragment");

 }
```

In your dialogFragmendFragment

```
   public void onAttachToParentFragment(CallBackInterface callBackInterface) {
        if (callBackInterface != null) {
            try {
                this.callBackInterface= callBackInterface;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(
                        callBackInterface.toString() + " must implement Callback");
            }
        }
```

Use callback function in the place you want in Dialog Fragment

```
callBackInterface.onClickAtOKButton(your data);
```

Comment: So with this code, i dont need to use interface in the "MainActivity"?

Comment: yes u dont need to use interface in the MainActivity .You can get callback from DialogFragment to Fragment

Comment: I have tried this **dFragment.onAttachToParentFragment(this);** line code. but for some reason i dont have "onAttachToParentFragment. It gives me only "onAttach" and "onAttachFragment"